# Peskin's QFT chapter 6 contour integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In page 178 of peskin QFT textbook equiation (6.5) gives us a contour integral:

\begin{equation}
A^{\mu}(x) = \int \frac{d^4k}{(2 \pi)^4} e^{-ikx} \frac{-ie}{k^2}\Big ( \frac{p'^{\mu}}{k \cdot p' + i \epsilon} - \frac{p^{\mu}}{k \cdot p - i \epsilon} \Big )
\end{equation}

And place the poles at $k^0= \pm |k|$ below the real axes. The other poles are found in $k \cdot p =0 $ and $k \cdot p' =0 $.

The result for the integration in the two cases $t>0$ and $t<0$ is given:

$t<0$
\begin{equation}
A^{\mu}(x) = \int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} e^{i(\vec{k} \vec{x})} e^{-(\vec{k} \vec{p}/p^0)t} \frac{(2\pi i)(ie)}{(2\pi )} \frac{p^{\mu }}{p^0}
\end{equation}

but I have tried to compute it and don't get the same result. Can anybody explain the steps I should take?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation self-contained, so one doesn't have to open the book to understand the question.

Comment: Hi C. Alvarez, please include the context of the problem into your question, so that someone could provide an answer without having a copy of the book in front of them.